# Can I "unsanitize" during a PDO SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sanitization

I am coding both client & server. The user inputs data in the browser, which is sent to my PHP code on the server.

I use `filter_input_array` on `$_GET[]` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` on the "name" field.

`O'Reilly` becomes `O&#39;Reilly`, and this is stored in the database.

Of course, the next time the client fetches the data and displays it in the browser, the user complains.

Is there any way to "unsanitize" when I `SELECT` the data from the MySql database using PDO?

Comment: The proper way is to store data properly in the database and not encoded in the wrong way. Probably using `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` would help

Comment: If you are using prepared statements and binding the values, you shouldn't need to do the sanitize in the first place.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen That worked, feel free to post it as an answer and I Will accept it. Nigel, when I Look at the code, I see that  am ***both*** sanitizing the input ***and*** binding d/b query parameters!  Maybe I need to rethink & refactor?

Comment: If you can 'give it a go' and comment out your filter_input_array, see how it works - always useful to properly understand how these things affect your site and the data it uses.

Comment: You are correct, of course. And, since I bind my query parameters, I don't need to sanitize (it was just part of something I was using to verify that mandatory `$_GET[]` parameters are present in the URL. I don't know how the sanitization slipped in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving data in the database the proper way is to store the data as it is used, meaning with the ' as is. Then you don't need to do anything to the data when it is displayed.

You can use the `FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES` flag to disable encoding for " or ' in the string. If you want to just get rid of HTML tags you can also use `strip_tags()` function instead for that value.

You always want to use parameters in the queries since that helps with SQL injection issues, but whether you want to strip tags, sanitize input or something else depends on what you want to do with the data. So sometimes you just use parameters, sometimes also sanitize.